# How to auto-connect to samba drive without pop-up

Tags: samba, elementary-os

Each time when I first open a Samba drive in Elementary OS it shows the following pop-up:

[image]

Then I must click on the "Connect" button.
Is it possible that it connects automatically when I click on it, without showing the pop-up? I wouldn't like it to auto-connect during boot, because the notebook can leave the LAN. The samba drive has anonymous access only.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was to add the network shares to the `/etc/fstab` permanently. It fails silently when the drive is not reachable. I followed the instructions here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

- Install cifs-utils:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
  ```
- /etc/fstab:

  ```
  //192.168.1.102/a/              /mnt/samba_a        cifs    guest,uid=userName,gid=groupName,iocharset=utf8 0   0
  ```
- Then check if the settings are correct:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```